# Remove position from json jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not want to display double the same product. If isbn repeats then do not display it double.

```js
{
  "products": [{
    "ident": "001",
    "isbn": "2332",
    "discount": "10%",
    "bookstore": "library1"
  }, {
    "ident": "002",
    "isbn": "2332",
    "discount": "20%",
    "bookstore": "library2"
  }, {
    "ident": "003",
    "isbn": "3422",
    "discount": "30%",
    "bookstore": "library3"
  }, ]
}

function getData() {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) { // get data from data.json
    var products = data.products;
    var tr = $("<tr>");
    var items = '';

    $.each(products, function(key, value) {
      items += "<tr position=" + value.bookstore + ">";
      items += "<td>" + value.ident + "</td>";
      items += "<td>" + value.isbn + "</td>";
      `enter code here`
      items += "<td>" + value.discount + "</td>";
      items += "<td>" + value.bookstore + "</td>";
      items += "</tr>";
    });

    $('#data').append(items); // show data in table
  });
```

Comment: Why so many repetitions in your question description?

Comment: nice mantra! what is the rule to know which one is kept or thrown away? the first one?

Comment: I many repetitions add by mistake. I sorry

Comment: @Piotr This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238602/javascript-remove-duplicates-of-objects-sharing-same-property-value

Comment: In td "bookstore"  see that it in two library

Answer (score 1):

You could keep hold of the list of ISBN's in an array, and then check if the array contains an ISBN before doing something with it.

```
var bookList = [];

$.each(products, function(key, value) {

  // Pushes value.isbn to the bookList array
  bookList.push(value.isbn);

  // If the IBSN is not present in bookList then act as if it's a new entry instead of repeating it.
  if (!bookList.includes(value.isbn)) {
    // Do something with the data here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Good approach. It is important to note that `Array.prototype.includes` is not currently supported in IE. If you choose to implement this approach, you will need to use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) as provided by _MDN_.

Comment: Ah yes, good point!

Comment: @JamesIves you may build the table on the fly and avoid to add rows containing duplicated values [fidde](https://jsfiddle.net/8kzmq02b/1/). What's your idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a simple `for` loop. For the sake of this question, I hard-coded your `JSON` data. However, you can implement the ajax request with the `$.getJSON()` routine in it's place (as you did above) and the result will be the same:

```js
var json = {
  "products": [{
    "ident": "001",
    "isbn": "2332",
    "discount": "10%",
    "bookstore": "library1"
  }, {
    "ident": "002",
    "isbn": "2332",
    "discount": "20%",
    "bookstore": "library2"
  }, {
    "ident": "003",
    "isbn": "3422",
    "discount": "30%",
    "bookstore": "library3"
  }, ]
};

var products = {};

for(var a = 0, len = json.products.length; a < len; a++) {
  if(products[json.products[a].isbn]) {
       products[json.products[a].isbn].bookstore = products[json.products[a].isbn].bookstore + "," + json.products[a].bookstore;
    } else {
      products[json.products[a].isbn] = json.products[a];
    }
}

$.each(products, function (key, value) {
 console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This routine adds each product to a new `products` object. Each object key is the `isbn` number of the product. If the `isbn` already exists, the bookstores that the product is sold in is updated to include the previous value and the new value. If the `isbn` does not exist, the product is added to the `products` object as a new product.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is great

Answer (score -1):

Insert into an array the ISBN then check with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if there exists in the array.

```
var arr = [

    {
        "ident":"001",
        "isbn":"2332",
        "discount":"10%",
        "bookstore": "library1"
    },

    {
        "ident":"002",
        "isbn":"2332",
        "discount":"20%",
        "bookstore": "library2"
    },

     {
        "ident":"003",
        "isbn":"3422",
        "discount":"30%",
        "bookstore": "library3"
    }
    ];

    var arrISBN = [];

    for(let index in arr) {

        if ( arrISBN.indexOf(arr[index].isbn) == -1  ) {
           arrISBN.push( arr[index].isbn);
            console.log("No duplicates");
        }


}
```