# Angular - Remove duplicates in array with same name element

Tags: angular

The problem is simple.

How can i filter this array with the 'alarma' element to get only one

```
0: {alarma: 1797, nroSerie: "8764368", nombre: "Alarma cable cortado", fechaInicio: 1566194460, fechaFin: 1566311460}
1: {alarma: 1797, nroSerie: "8764368", nombre: "Alarma cable cortado", fechaInicio: 1566311460, fechaFin: 1566311580}
2: {alarma: 1797, nroSerie: "8764368", nombre: "Alarma cable cortado", fechaInicio: 1566311580, fechaFin: null}
```

Comment: `array.filter()`

Comment: array.filter will return all elements with specified condition, it's opposite. You can use Map, 'alarma' value as key and whole element as value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Remove duplicates of objects sharing same property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238602/javascript-remove-duplicates-of-objects-sharing-same-property-value)

Comment: I try something like this but isn´t exactly that i need it: array.filter((el, i, a) => i === a.indexOf(el));

Answer (score 2):

U can use lodash and function uniqBy from the library, it will be the fastest way :)

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic function `GetDistinctValues(Source, Filterkey)` that will take any data array and any filter key of the objects in the array

Try like this:

```
  dataarray = [
    { alarma: 1797, nroSerie: "8764368", nombre: "Alarma cable cortado", fechaInicio: 1566194460, fechaFin: 1566311460 },
    { alarma: 1797, nroSerie: "8764368", nombre: "Alarma cable cortado", fechaInicio: 1566311460, fechaFin: 1566311580 },
    { alarma: 1797, nroSerie: "8764368", nombre: "Alarma cable cortado", fechaInicio: 1566311580, fechaFin: null }
  ]

  ngOnInit() {
    var distinctValue = this.GetDistinctValues(this.dataarray, 'alarma')
    console.log(distinctValue)
  }


  GetDistinctValues(Source: Array<any>, FilterKey: string = null): Array<any> {
    let DistinctArray = [];
    try {
      Source.forEach((e) => {
        if (FilterKey !== null && FilterKey !== undefined && FilterKey !== "") {
          if (DistinctArray.filter(((DE) => DE[FilterKey] === e[FilterKey])).length <= 0)
            DistinctArray.push(e);
        }
        else {
          if (DistinctArray.indexOf(e) === -1)
            DistinctArray.push(e);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      DistinctArray = [];
    }
    return DistinctArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the

> array.indexOf(obj)

function. If the array has the same element already the indexOf function will return some valid index. before doing the

> array.push(obj)

check the

> array.indexOf(obj).

function first

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of duplicates by a given key without using `lodash` library you can do the following:

For a given array `[{a: 5, b: 7}, {a: 5, b: 99}, {a: 6, b: 1}, {a: 6, b: 0}]` the expected result can be `[{a: 5, b: 99}, {a: 6, b: 0}]` (the last values are taken)

to implement this simply:

1. Create an object having a key as a value of 'a' property:

```
const array = [{a: 5, b: 7}, {a: 5, b: 99}, {a: 6, b: 1}, {a: 6, b: 0}];
const unique = array.reduce((acc, value) => { 
  acc[value.a] = value; 
  return acc;
}, {});
```

The `unique` object will be the following:

```
{"5":{"a":5,"b":99},"6":{"a":6,"b":0}}
```

2. Take the values of this object using:

```
const result = Object.values(unique);
```

The `result` value will be:

```
[{"a":5,"b":99},{"a":6,"b":0}]
```

**If you want only the first item of a duplicate to be taken change the code to**:

```
const array = [{a: 5, b: 7}, {a: 5, b: 99}, {a: 6, b: 1}, {a: 6, b: 0}];
const unique = array.reduce((acc, value) => { 
  acc[value.a] = acc[value.a] || value; // note the changes at this line
  return acc;
}, {});
const result = Object.values(unique);
```

The output will be:

```
[{"a":5,"b":7},{"a":6,"b":1}]
```