# Removing partial duplicates from an array

Tags: javascript

-bit of a noobie question, but I have an array that looks like this:

```
[["john",13],
["jack",12],
["judy",14],
["john",18]]
```

In the event there is a duplicate name, I would like to remove the element with the highest score, such that it looks like this:

```
[["john",13],
["jack",12],
["judy",14]]
```

Standard method of removing duplicates don't work in this case and I am just wondering if anyone knows how this could be done?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Remove duplicates of objects sharing same property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238602/javascript-remove-duplicates-of-objects-sharing-same-property-value)

Comment: Thanks. Found lots of useful information on here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method and `Map` to get unique values and then you can use  spread syntax to get array of arrays.

```js
const data = [["john",13], ["jack",12], ["judy",14], ["john",18]]

const result = data.reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  if(!r.get(k) || v < r.get(k)) r.set(k, v)
  return r;
}, new Map)

console.log([...result])
```

Comment: `.entries()` is not really required. Just spreading a `Map` creates the 2D array of entries